# I am new to TCL.I just want to extract interface name by giving ip address in TCL and Expect using regexp

Tags: tcl, expect

My input data is this:

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.10      10.1.1.1        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.20      20.1.1.2        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         192.168.2.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         192.168.1.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

I want a way to extract interface names given an IP address. For example, if the input is `192.168.1.1`, the output should be `GigabitEthernet0/2`

Can someone help me? I tried this:

```
regexp -line -- ^.*?(?=(?:\\..*?)?\\s$ip) $input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest way to solve this sort of thing in general is to parse out the lines to make some sort of mapping, probably in an array, and then to do the lookup in that. To parse the data, we'll use `regexp -all -line -inline`; that's a *very* useful combination, since it produces lists that we can process with `foreach` to make our map.

```
# You might read this data from another program or from a file; that's good too...
set data "Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.10      10.1.1.1        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.20      20.1.1.2        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         192.168.2.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         192.168.1.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up   "

# Build the mapping; the “-” in the variable name list is for skipping some unwanted stuff
foreach {- interface ip} [regexp -all -line -inline {^(\w+/\d+)\s+([\d.]+)} $data] {
    set mapToIP($interface) $ip
    set mapToInterface($ip) $interface
}
```

Then we can just do the lookup easily whenever we want:

```
set myIP 192.168.1.1
puts "$myIP is mapped to interface: $mapToInterface($myIP)"
```

FWIW, you *really* need to make sure that you always put REs in braces, as it avoids all sorts of problems. While it isn't a 100% rule that you should always brace your REs, you should do that anyway until you absolutely cannot avoid building a RE from individual pieces at runtime, which is a pretty rare thing in practical code.